# State not updating on button Click

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I am new to react. I have 3 buttons in my components and I am applying a class active based on the selection.(i.e button that is clicked ).

Code is,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './style.module.scss';

const rootClass = 'headers';

function Headers(props) {
  const {
    content, onClick, displayMonth,
  } = props;

  const [activeMonth, setActiveMonth] = useState(true);
  const [activeWeek, setActiveWeek] = useState(false);
  const [activeYear, setActiveYear] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'week':
        setActiveMonth(false);
        setActiveWeek(true);
        setActiveYear(false);
        console.log('Week:', activeWeek);
        console.log('Month:', activeMonth);
        console.log('Year:', activeYear);
        onClick(value);

        break;
      case 'month':
        setActiveMonth(true);
        setActiveWeek(false);
        setActiveYear(false);
        console.log('Week:', activeWeek);
        console.log('Month:', activeMonth);
        console.log('Year:', activeYear);
        onClick(value);
        break;
      case 'year':
        setActiveYear(true);
        setActiveWeek(false);
        setActiveMonth(false);
        onClick(value);

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  return (
    <section className={rootClass}>
      <div className={styles[`${rootClass}__outer-container`]}>
       <div className={`${styles[`${rootClass}__column-container-side`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__calendar-type`]}`}>
          <button
            type="button"
            className={activeYear ? `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-year`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-active`]}` : `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-year`]}`}
            onClick={() => handleClick('year')}
          >
            Year
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className={activeMonth ? `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-month`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-active`]}` : `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-month`]}`}
            onClick={() => handleClick('month')}
          >
            Month
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className={activeWeek ? `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-week`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-active`]}` : `${styles[`${rootClass}__event-button`]} ${styles[`${rootClass}__event-week`]}`}
            onClick={() => handleClick('week')}
          >
            Week
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
export default Headers;
```

The state doesn't seem to update when the buttons are toggled . The button state remains the same when I console log. The class active isn't getting applied. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `() => handleClick('month')}` -- don't you mean `('month') => handleClick(value)`?  Shouldn't the argument be passed in the left side of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and the parameter name be given something generic?  (P.S. You'll want to update the others, too.)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand your question. Isn't month passed on the left side of the arrow function? Like this?  const handleClick = (value) => {}

Comment: The React portion looks fine to update the React state. One option is to check that the styles object contains what you expect. If `styles['myClassName']` is returning null or undefined it probably isn't going to render out the class name.

Comment: You have lots of console.logs.  What are the results of those?  Are they all coming out fine and right, and it's just the state isn't updating?

Comment: @HoldoffHunger  - The states in the console log return the previous state value and it isn't updating

Comment: I think I understand now.  After importing your css file, you can ignore it!  Set your classname like `className={activeYear ? {rootClass + '__event-button'} : 'some other classname' }`.  You don't need to do `className={activeMonth ? ``${styles[``${rootClass}__event-button``]}`, unless I'm misunderstanding what your trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  I am using css modules, so i am importing css file and using styles[]

Comment: @NickRoth I don't see the active class applied to the element